# Allow filtering only "hot posts" in custom filters

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

When I go to https://stackexchange.com/filters/new, I am presented a way to subscribe to a feed of questions from any number of Stack Exchange sites with specific tags. This is awesome. But, it would be even more awesome if there was a switch to let me limit the filter to only questions which have reached the "Hot Network Questions" list.

There are certain interesting high-traffic sites with certain interesting high-traffic tags, on which such a filtered feed would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This could be improved by going into the [Hot Network questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) and then filtering out the questions by tag there.

A lot of times, I also want to see Hot Questions by site so I recommend expanding this proposal to allowing a custom filter *in* the HNQ, allowing the filtering of questions by site, age, and tags.